# wordpress rest api custom endpoint - add header in request API

Tags: php, wordpress, api, rest

it's my first time to create rest api with custom endpoint in wordpress the api is working fine but the problem is i want to add key and value in the header when i send request to the api , to avoid using the api in postman without adding these key and value in the header
here is the code that create the api :

```
add_action( 'rest_api_init', 'wl_posts');
function wl_posts(){
 register_rest_route('w1/v1','fav/',[
   'methods' => 'POST',
   'callback' => 'test',
   'header'  => 'username : test'
]);
```

any help ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a function from you callback that gathers the param you need, and do what you need after:

```
<?php

function callback_name( $data ) {
    
    $your_var = $data->get_param( 'param_name' );
    
    // Do other stuff that you need to do

}

?>
```

Comment: thank you very much it worked , I also found that you can add header in the request using $data->get_header($key , $value)

Comment: Yes that is another way to accomplish.  Glad it worked for you